# Relative path in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter in my app and I have difficult struggle with relative paths. This is the case:

> root/application/views/assets/css/style.css
>
> root/application/views/templates/file.php

So in the file.php I call style.css as follows:

```
../assets/css/style.css
```

And it is not working. In the browser console it says the css have not beed found because it is searching it in root/assets/css/style.css

What is happening here ?

Comment: I suggest you to use full url address to your static files.

Comment: Because you don't use relative path for your assets (CSS, JS, img). The browser don't know the relative path of your server. Use absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the URL helper.

You can load wherever it required as below:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

And then access the needed files like this:

```
echo base_url("assets/css/style.css");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your assets directory from `APPPATH . 'views/'` to `root`. Visitors, user agents have no permission for views directory. Your app structure should be like:

```
-application/
-assets/
-system/
-.htaccess
-index.php
```